# Login con diferentes usuarios

Tags: php, bootstrap, codeigniter, mvc, phpmyadmin

Hola compañeros de stack overflow.

Tengo el siguiente **Login** con 3 tipos de usuarios.

Sucede que al momento de entrar al controlador login. Se queda en blanco y no se que mas sucede. Funcionaba sin tener que usar el `switch` y los diferentes usuarios. Pero ahora que integre esto, no se que podría estar fallando.

Gracias de antemano por el apoyo.

**Controlador**

```
    public function login()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('usuario', 'Nombre', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cve_acceso', 'Contraseña', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('tipo_usuario', 'Tipo', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {

        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $clave   = $_POST['cve_acceso'];
        $tipo    = $_POST['tipo_usuario'];

        $datos = $this->Sesion_model->inicioM($usuario, $clave, $tipo);
        if ($datos > 0) {                
            $_SESSION['user_logged'] = true;
            switch ($this->session->userdata('tipo_usuario')){
                case 'administrador':
                    redirect("ayuntamiento/adminprogramas");
                break;

                case 'presidente':
                    redirect("ayuntamiento/presiprogramas");
                break;

                case 'empleado':
                     redirect("ayuntamiento/programas");
                break; 
            }    
        } else {
            redirect("sesion/inicio", "refresh");
        }
    }
}
```

**Vista**

```
 <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: #808080">
    <div class="container">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/gob-02_opt.png" class="center-block img-responsive">    <center>
            <h3>SISTEMA INTEGRAL PARA LA ADMINISTRACIÓN DE APOYO CIUDADANO | INICIO</h3>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <form id="form" name="form" method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>sesion/login">   
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-md-offset-4 col-md-5">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!--<label for="tipo">Tipo de Usuario</label>-->
                    <select class="form-control" id="tipo_usuario" name="tipo_usuario" style="color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #A9A9A9">
                        <option value="">Seleccione tipo de usuario</option>
                        <option value="administrador">Administrador</option>
                        <option value="presidente">Cabildo</option>
                        <option value="empleado">Empleado</option>
                    </select>
                </div>        
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-md-offset-4 col-md-5">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!--<label for="nombre">Nombre</label>-->
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Introduce nombre de usuario">
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-md-offset-4 col-md-5"">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!--<label for="password">Contraseña</label>-->
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" id="cve_acceso" name="cve_acceso" placeholder="Introduce contraseña">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-offset-5 col-md-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    Acceder
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <label>¿No estas registrado?</label>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>empleados/registroE"> Crear Cuenta</a>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

**Modelo**

```
public function inicioM($usuario, $clave, $tipo)
{

    $query = $this->db
        ->select("*")
        ->from('usuarios')
        ->where(array('nombre' => $usuario, 'cve_acceso' => $clave, 'tipo_usuario' => $tipo))
        ->count_all_results();

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: has revisado el log de errores?

Comment: Lo acabo de revisar, pero no hay nada y mucho menos con fecha actual

Comment: pues entonces se quedará en blanco porque el usuario no tiene ningun tipo de los contemplados en el `switch`. Tendras que poner un caso por defecto

Comment: Pero si lo tiene, y acabo de agregar el default para que muestre un error. Pero aun asi se queda en blanco. Gracias por el apoyo

Comment: supongo que estás comprobando que realmente el form valida y entra en el if, no?

Comment: Si así es, si entra e incluso manda los parámetros pero no hay respuesta. Si quito la condición de **switch** y solamente dejo que compruebe que existe el usuario con los 3 datos nombre, contraseña y tipo. Da acceso sin ningún problema.

Comment: tienes los errores y warnings activados? a veces no se puede redirigir porque se hace mediante headers, y no funciona si ya se ha enviado contenido. Pero eso sale en un warning,

Comment: Si los errores del servidor

Comment: Yo diría que la variable `$datos` tiene la info, pero no se ha poblado la sesión, por lo que `$this->session` está vacía. Tendrías que comprobar directamente via `$datos['tipo_usuario']` pero además asegurarte de que se pueblen las variables de sesión antes de redirigir

Comment: estas validando el tipo de usuario con 
$this->session->userdata('tipo_usuario'), pero en ningún parte seteas dicho valor de session.! Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debe ser la variable $datos, La variable esta obteniendo todo lo que tiene tu tabla usuarios, deberías entrar al array para poder hacer que el switch funcione,la variable debería quedar algo así: `$datos[0]['tipo_usuario']` o `$datos['tipo_usuario']`.

Espero que este sea la solución a tu problema.
Saludos.